# Count elements in table a that have two exactly matching elements in table b

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables and need to get a count of all entries from table A that have two specific matches in table B. Table B has tables A's Id as a foreign key.

```
Table a
ID       Name
1        Foo
2        Bar
3        John
4        Jane

Table b
aID     Value
1       12
1       12
2       8
3       8
3       12
4       12
4       8
```

I now need a count of all names in table A that have both value 8 AND 12 in table B at least once.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a join b on a.id = b.aId where b.value = 8 and b.value = 12
```

gets me 0 results. The correct result should be 2 (John and Jane).

**edit**:
Obviously, @Larnu is correct and 8 will never be 12.

Also, I should have clarified that there can be two or more of a single value in table B for any table A id, but none of the other (e.g. 8 twice but no 12). I updated the table to reflect that.

Comment: `where b.value = 8 and b.value = 12 ` think about it, in what scenario can that ever be true? If `value = 8` then `value != 12` `8 != 12`. Do you, perhaps, want an `IN`?

Comment: @Larnu thanks, but an 'IN' would return all entries from table A, because they all have at least one matching element in table B. I need a count of elements in A that have 8 AND 12 in B.

Comment: That likely isn't the full solution, @ChrisKoe, however, that doesn't change my point. `8` and `12` are not the same value. It is **impossible** for `value` to have the value `8` and `12` at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subquery to get the number of times 8 and 12 appear for each row will do the trick:

```
select count(id) from 
(select id, sum(case when b.Value = 8 then 1 else 0 end) as ct8,
sum(case when b.Value = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as ct12
from a inner join b on a.id = b.aID
group by a.id) as t
where ct8 >= 1 and ct12 >=1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ff9d702604e328147cfc7d971008138)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT b.aID FROM b
             WHERE a.ID = b.aID
             GROUP BY b.aID
             HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

If you want specifically `value = 8 or 12` then add `AND b.value IN(8,12)` to the inner query

Comment: Wouldn't give the correct output if for example (1, 8) exists twice and there is no (1, 12).

Comment: You are correct, but it doesn't seem that it is an option from the data sample..

Answer (score 0):

Joining is not the answer here. You need a WHERE clause that includes a correlated subquery that checks your condition using COUNT() or EXISTS(). One of the following should do.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) ​FROM B ​WHERE B.aID = A.ID ​AND B.VALUE IN (8, 12)) = 2
```

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.aID = A.ID AND B.VALUE = 8)
AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.aID = A.ID AND B.VALUE = 12)
```